# User name and password prompt constantly reappears

Tags: microsoft-outlook

[internet e-mail enter the user name and password for the following server http://cdn.tinkertry.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/outlookemaildialogue.jpg](http://cdn.tinkertry.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/outlookemaildialogue.jpg)

I keep getting this message in a pop up box - just reappears every few moments.

Comment: sounds like a script error.  What is the website?

Comment: It's neither a WWW site nor a WWW browser, Daniel.  **It's Microsoft Outlook**.  Perhaps the `microsoft-outlook` tag that the questioner put on the question was too subtle.  I've added a picture of this dialogue box.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your email server is rejecting the username / password pair. It reappears each time Outlook tries to connect to the server.

The server may be experiencing temporary problems, or you may need to provide the username/password to Outlook. It's possible that your email account was hacked and somebody changed the password on you.

Try using the "webmail" service of your email provider and see if your username/password combo works there.